# Why are the OnClickListeners set in custom view inflated in a DialogFragment not being called when the views are clicked?

Tags: android

I have the following code that builds a dialog and sets listeners on the views contained in the custom view within the dialog.

```kotlin
 // relevant imports
 import android.app.AlertDialog
 import android.app.Dialog
 import android.util.Log
 import android.view.LayoutInflater
 import android.widget.Button
 import android.widget.ImageView
 import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment

 override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return activity?.let {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
            val inflater = requireActivity().layoutInflater;

            val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.proj_submissn_dialog_content, null)

            view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iv_close_button).setOnClickListener {
                Log.d(TAG, "image view clicked...")
            }

            view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_yes).setOnClickListener {
                Log.d(TAG, "button view clicked...")
            }

            builder.setView(view)
            builder.create()
        } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
    }
```

Nothing gets logged in the console when either the image or button view is clicked. Am I doing something wrong?

The imageView is set to clickable in the xml layout file

```xml
  ...
  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_close_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/close"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/close"
        android:contentDescription="@string/close_dialog_text"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true" />
  ...
```

Comment: What version of AlertDialog are you using?  Can you show the line where you import AlertDialog?

Comment: @MichaelKrause, I have updated the code with the imports

Comment: Weird.  I don't see any version of AlertDialog.Builder that has a setView method that takes two params.  What version of the Android SDK are you building against?

Comment: Oh my bad, that happened while I was editing the code, I just removed it

Comment: Got it.  :)  I think your code looks OK.  Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the Log statements in the debugger?  Do they get hit?  Also, might try just running `adb logcat` from the command line and see if the log messages are showing up there.  PS: As an aside, you can just use it.layoutInflater instead of requireActivity().layoutInflater since you've already got the captured non-null activity from your let statement.

Comment: on running `adb logcat`, I saw that they were actually logged to console. Then I restarted the app and the log statements are printed to logcat. Thanks.